# John Resig inheritance class and overridden methods - invoking wrong method

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I am trying to use John Resig's inheritance class to extend some classes I am developing.
These classes have methods that are overridden. Nonetheless, the original version of those methods should be invoked as well.
My problem is that when I try to invoke a method on the super class, it invokes the method that overrides the original one.

Take the following code as an example:

```
var A = Class.extend({
    init: function(){
        this.doStuff(); // this invokes doStuff from B instead of A
    },

    doStuff: function(){
      // does stuff on the super class
    }

});

var B = A.extend({
    init: function(){
        this._super();

        this.doStuff();
    },

    doStuff: function(){
        // does stuff on the sub class
    }
});
```

When I create an instance of B:

```
var test = B.create();
```

as soon as the init method from A (super class) is invoked, it is the doStuff from B that is invoked instead of the one on the A class.

Is there anything I can do in order to prevent this from happening?

Comment: FWIW, I've added examples to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anything I can do in order to prevent this from happening?

Yes, you need to call the method by explicitly refering to the one that you want to invoke, instead of dynamically dispatching it on the instance:

```
var A = Class.extend({
    init: function(){
        A.prototype.doStuff.call(this); // always invokes doStuff from A
    },
    doStuff: function(){
        // does stuff on the super class
    }
});
```

Dynamic dispatch is the natural and expected behaviour. Usually you'd also have a `super` call in `B::doStuff` to `A::doStuff`.

Notice that this doesn't have anything to do with `super` calls or using Resig's syntactic sugar.